# Problem with installing windows service using CC.NET and MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to install a windows service using MSBuild and CCNET. I am using MSBuild Extension pack [WindowsService](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.5.0/html/258a18b7-2cf7-330b-e6fe-8bc45db381b9.htm)
task to install and start the windows service as part of automated build. The script section look like this

```
<!--install service-->
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Install" ServiceName="$(PrServiceName)" ServicePath="$(PrServicePath)" User="$(User)" />

<!--set service to run automatically on restart-->
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="SetAutomatic" ServiceName="$(PrServiceName)" />

<!--start service-->
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Start" ServiceName="$(PrServiceName)" ServicePath="$(PrServicePath)" User="$(User)" />
```

Now as soon as the the first task runs to install the service, it fails with the following error

E:\Data\cc_temp\Projects\cubic\intranet\pr\pr.build (137,3):  error : Install Service failed with code: 'AccessDenied'

I assume this is because the script is running under cruise control service user account which does not have the appropriate permissions for installing a windows service.

I would just like to give minimal permissions to the cruise control user account instead of giving the full administrative rights.

Does anyone out there knows how can i achieve this?

Awaiting
Nabeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nabeel you are on the right track, it has to be a permissions issue. We do this all the time in our build using the same tools and it works. Have you checked to see which account the service is running as? and using the same user account to run your cruisecontrol? at least then you would possibly prove/disprove the permissions issue.

Comment: Hi Alex, I was acatulaly using unc path for the *ServicePath* property in the tasks. After changing it to absolute path, everything seems to be working fine.